# ASP.NET Core 2.0 read: Options in razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) guide, I'm trying to show on an ASP.NET Core 2.0 page the settings values.

In startup.cs I added some services:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

where MyOptions is defined here:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class OptionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SubOptions _SubOptions;

        public OptionsController(IOptions<SubOptions> options)
        {
            _SubOptions = (SubOptions) options;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var RefreshTime = _SubOptions.RefreshTime;
            return Content($"RefreshTime = {RefreshTime}");
        }
    }

    public class MyOptions
    {
        public MyOptions()
        {
            SubOpt = new SubOptions();
        }

        public SubOptions SubOpt { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubOptions
    {
        public SubOptions()
        {
            RefreshTime = 5;
        }

        public int RefreshTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Trying from startup.cs I can access to the RefreshTime setting.
Now I want to do this directly in cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@model MyOptions
@inject IOptions<MyOptions> Options
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<
<h3>@Model.Message</h3>
<br />
<div>
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <h4>Sub Options</h4>
    <p><b>Refresh time</b> @Options.Value.SubOptions.RefreshTime</p>
</div>
```

The page doesn't load but I don't see any errors in the output console of VisualStudio nor in the one of the browser.

Furthermore the page doesn't load even if I just put there the first @using directive, removing all the other options stuff.

Then I checked I have that package installed and it seems so:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is there something other I need to do?

### UPDATE

As @Niladri pointed out I mixed MVC and Razor pages (I will open a separate question on this topic).

Now I removed the controller class because is not needed for razor pages. 
Anyway the main problem is that if I add `@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options` on any page, this doesn't allow the page loading.

But I cannot see any errors or exceptions.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Output window?

Comment: how about putting the value in viewbag inside the controller action ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/page):

> The @page Razor directive makes the file into an MVC action — which means that it can handle requests. **@page must be the first Razor directive on a page.**

Hence the solution is extremely simple, just reorder the directives:

```
@page
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptions<MyOptions> Options
@model AboutModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<
<h3>@Model.Message</h3>
<br />
<div>
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <p><b>Refresh time</b> @Options.Value.SubOpt.RefreshTime</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you still need to add the below code in your startup.cs file

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
```

also you need to set the default value of RefreshTime in appsettings.json and then use the below code in.cshtml page

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
@using <enter the namespace for your MyOptions class here>;
@inject IOptions<MyOptions> Options
@page
@model AboutModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}
<
<h3>@Model.Message</h3>
<br />
<div>
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <h4>Sub Options</h4>
    <p><b>Refresh time</b> @Options.Value.SubOpt.RefreshTime</p>
</div>
```

let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your answer - I apologize. But those 3 lines are already there, see my question. The problem is the page won't load, it loads instead my Index. This happens even if on a blank page I add only `@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options`

Comment: I have changed model with using in my code for the my options class . There should be a single model only. Btw are you using a MVC razor view or razor pages only?

Comment: Razor pages don't require controller. May be you have mixed up

Comment: I'm trying to use razor only pages... but I'm confused about documentation. It's not so clear to me the difference in coding between them

Comment: Razor pages don't have a controller. They are much like webpage with code behind. A regular MVC  controller won't work

Comment: Ok, I removed the controller and adapted the code following your example. But as said, the @using directive prevents the page loading. I don't see any information in the outputs (debug and ASP.NET Server). How should I debug this behavior?