# How to retrieve a service in razor pages with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

In ASP.NET Core 2 application I set up some services:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
              options.UseSqlServer(
                      Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext"))
  );
  services.AddHangfire(options => 
              options.UseSqlServerStorage(
                      Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext"))
  );

  services.AddOptions();
  services.Configure<MySettings>(options => 
              Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Bind(options)
  );
  services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

  services.AddScoped<IMyContext, MyContext>();
  services.AddTransient<IFileSystem, FileWrapper>();
  services.AddTransient<Importer, Importer>();
}
```

In `program.cs` I'm able to retrieve my own Service:

```
var host = BuildWebHost(args);
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var ip = services.GetRequiredService<Importer>();
    Task task = ip.ImportListAsync();
}
```

Now I'm trying to understand how to do the same when I don't have the host variable, like in any other C# class or even if a cshtml page:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRefresh()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    // host is not defined: how to retrieve it?
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var ip = services.GetRequiredService<Importer>();
        Task task = ip.ImportListAsync();
    }

    return RedirectToPage();
}
```

Comment: What is `hosts`? Do you expect us to magically guess what you assigned to a variable? Also, did you even read the DI tutorial in Microsoft's docs?

Comment: Read [this basic tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection) and ask a real question when you are not able to continue.

Comment: I apologize. I missed one line in copy/paste. Sorry for that.

Comment: I read that document, but I'm very confused because they're talking about Views and Controller (MVC) but I'm not using MVC hence I thought it's not applicable to my scenario. I'm not sure on which documentation I should rely on.

Comment: Your question title says "Retrieve a Service from cshtml". CSHTML => Razor => View. How come you are not using MVC if your question title mentions MVC?

Comment: I learned here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867405/asp-net-core-2-0-read-options-in-razor-page) that Razor pages doesn't use a Controller: "Razor pages don't require controller.". In fact I don't have one in my application. And another confusion is usually Views are called in MVC, but in Core 2 they call Pages...

Comment: The fact that you are using a micro-MVC like Razor Pages does not change the fact that you are using MVC (as a Framework, not as a Pattern). Yes, that article applies as well

Comment: I'm sorry for didnt' understand that.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a framework. Whether or not you use the pattern (Models, Views and Controllers, all strictly separated) is up to you. Razor Pages live inside MVC. Whatever applies to MVC, it applies to Razor Pages

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dependency injection is possible in asp.net core razor pages as well.

You can do constructor injection in your page model class.

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private IFileSystem fileSystem;
    public LoginModel(IFileSystem fileSystem)
    {
        this.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostRefresh()
    {
       // now you can use this.fileSystem
       //to do : return something
    }
}
```

Dependency injection is also possible in the pages :). Simply use the `inject` directive.

```
@model YourNameSpace.LoginModel 
@inject IFileSystem FileSystem;
<h1>My page</h1>
// Use FileSystem now
```

Comment: Not working for me. Is there something else that needs to be configured?

Comment: From where and how is `IFileSystem FileSystem;` incjected? For example the [bakery tutorial](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tutorial/bakery/working-with-data) has this line `public IndexModel(BakeryContext db) => this.db = db;` to inject the database context into the page class. But it is unclear how this "automagic" happens. Where is the glue code to inject that class BakeryContext? I am asking for a friend.

Comment: @surfmuggle, the IFileSystem is inject on the ConfigureServices method (see initial post) in this line: `services.AddTransient<IFileSystem, FileWrapper>();`

Comment: @surfmuggle, in your case, you have 2 lines of code: `private readonly BakeryContext db;` and `public IndexModel(BakeryContext db) => this.db = db;`. The first one is injected into the second. The expression `=> this.db = db;` just says "hey, I want you to pass me that BakeryContext object that is already defined as a property". That's mostly it.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 6 the procedure has been simplified.

In a .NET 6 Core Web App (Razor Pages) you need to add the service interface to implementation mapping to the Web Application Builder in Program.cs as follows: `builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyDependency, MyDependency>();` More information can be found at [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

When you've done that you can use dependency injection in your page model class as described above.