# Global Variables in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm trying to get more clarification on an already asked question.  Because I'm a new user, I can't comment yet (You must have 50 reputation to comment).

In regards to [Global Variables in ASP.Net Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654307/global-variables-in-asp-net-core-2)

@nurdyguy comments that "The dependency injection built in to the framework will populate the options variable".

```
var repo = new DB();
```

More code to demonstrate the problem:

```
    public class Secrets
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            .
            .
            .

            System.Action<Secrets> opts = (opt =>
            {
                opt.ConnectionString = Configuration["ConnectionString"];
            });
            services.Configure(opts);
            services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Secrets>>().Value);
        }
    }

    public sealed class DB
    {
        private string _connectionString;

        public DB(Secrets secrets)
        {
            _connectionString = secrets.ConnectionString;
        }
    }

    public class testModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            DB db = new DB();
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to instantiate the class, I receive a the following compile time error:

Error CS7036
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'secrets' of 'DB(Secrets)'

I've followed the code example correctly I'm sure.  Is their another way to instantiate the class?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/47464619/34092 ? See what they did with `IFileSystem`? You need to do that here.

Comment: Thank you @mjwills, the link provided gave me with a solution that works.  I'm still completely in the dark as to how\why DI works.  Thanks so much for your persistence and patience with a new user.  This is a shit question that I'm sure no one will find useful but my day is certainly better now.  Cheers 

Comment: When you are new to something, learning is hard and takes time. Nothing to be ashamed about. Great to hear that the link helped.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you are trying to create an instance of PropertySalesRepository using `new` that calls the constructor that requires a prop of the type MDUOptions.

When creating an instance with `new` you do not get the class with injected properties.

To get the instance of the class with injected properties the easiest way is to inject it into your controller.

Comment: He is trying to create an instance of PropertySalesRepository with ´new´. However PropertySalesRepository has a constructor that requires MDUOptions as a parameter. Injecting PropertySalesRepository should solve this if he has already followed the instructions in the linked answer.