# Getting Dot.Net Core AppSettings in a Class, and I'm not using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Lots of answers to this question, if you're using MVC, but what if you're not using MVC?  I have a class of **Student**, and it has all the Crud in it.  I can't use any of the examples because of the call to the class. I'm new to Core but have been using Web Forms and MVC for some time.

When I make a call as shown for an example:

```
Student s = new Student();
s.FullName = "Sam";
s.Update;
```

I get the error that IConfiguration or IOptions is needed, depending on how I'm trying to call the AppSettings.

Startup.cs

```
   IConfigurationSection appSetting = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
   services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSetting);
```

Student Class

```
   public class Student
     {
         private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSetting;

              public Student(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
              {
                   _appSetting = appSettings;
              }
```

Where it's called in the Student class

```
public Student GetStudent(Guid StudentGUid)
      {
           var Conn = _appSetting.Value.ApplicationConn;

           using (IDbConnection con = new SqlConnection(Conn))
           {
```

Where I call class on page .cs

```
      Student sa = new Student();
      sa.GetStudent(new Guid("2b583b82-0337-425b-ac73-3830bc20253f"));
      var s = sa.LastName;
```

The error:

*There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter'appSetting .... , which makes sense. But this is where I go off the rails, as I can't just put in the IOption value because it always comes out null.

AppSettings Class

```
public class AppSettings
     {
          public string ApplicationID { get; set; }
          public string ApplicationUrl { get; set; }
          public string ApplicationConn { get; set; }
     }
```

JSON File

```
 "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
           "Default": "Information",
           "Microsoft": "Warning",
           "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
 },
 "AppSettings": {
      "ApplicationID": "Some Guid",
      "ApplicationUrl": "xxxxxx",
      "ApplicationConn": "Connection String"
 },
 "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Comment: Why does a `Student` need to know about application settings? It seems like your design is the problem here.

Comment: It's where I pull the connection string.

Comment: Again, a `Student` object should never need to know about connection strings - that's not its responsibility. Instead, you should rather have some sort of repository to retrieve and persist `Student` objects.

Comment: I get that, but our object classes are self contained with CRUD operations in them.  Hence the need for a connection string, app Id ...  ectra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a Student object using `new Student();`, but in the constructor you are requiring an `IOptions<AppSettings>` as an argument, and that's the exception you get. So yeah, it will always come off as null because you are not providing it.

As Ian suggested in his comment, you should reconsider your design. Why does the Student himself would require a connection string? You couple your domain object with database access. What I might propose is a StudentRepository, and I might code it like this:

```cs
public interface IStudentRepository
{
   Student GetStudentById(Guid studentId);
}
```

```cs
public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository 
{
   private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSetting;

   public StudentRepository (IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
   {
      _appSetting = appSettings;
   }

   public Student GetStudentById(Guid studentId)
   {
      // your code here
   }
}
```

And you will register it as:
`services.AddSingleton<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();`

Then in your page that you mentioned you will have to inject the `IStudentRepository`and use this instead of `new Student();`

*Sidenote:*
The above proposition might help you test (either in development time or in unit tests) your code, as you can swap out the DB-based implementation with a mock one

Comment: This is something I was trying to avoid, which was pulling the CRUD methods out of the Student class.

Comment: So won't I get the same issue when calling the StudentRepository, that it'll require IOptions<AppSettings>?

Comment: Yes, but you won't have to make a new instance each time, you will have a single instance and the AppSettings will be injected in the constructor. The way you have built your Student class, you require an IOptions but you never provide it, you use new Student();. Also, you say you are not using MVC and you talk about pages. What technology are you using?

Comment: Asp.net core web application with Razor pages ... not MVC

Comment: Maybe this will clear things up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47463206/how-to-retrieve-a-service-in-razor-pages-with-dependency-injection

Comment: OK, I got it working ... just needed to inject the interface into the page.

This is just so much work.  It was so much faster with Web Forms and object classes.  All of our business logic is handled through stored procedures and is updated quarterly so EF would mean a remake of the site.  And having the class methods in the object class was simple as: 

'
Student.GetStudent(SomeGuid);
Do something
Student.Save();
'
Progress I guess ... Thanks for the help.